# Não estou conseguindo enviar dados do formulario para o banco mysql

Tags: php, mysql

arquivo de conexão

```
<?php
   $servidor = "dsadasd.com.br";
   $usuario = "ttt";
   $senha = "ttt";
   $dbname = "cadastro";

   //Criar a conexao
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

   if(!$conn){
       die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }else{
       //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
   }      
?>
```

index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" media="screen">
   </head>

            <title>Central de Matrículas - Bem me quer</title>
<body>
<body background="http://www.palmeiradasmissoes-rs.com.br/new/city.png" bgproperties="fixed">
<?php
    // Inclui o arquivo com a função valida_cpf
    include('valida-cpf.php');
    session_destroy();
    ?>  

<div id="area">

    <form id="formulario" autocomplete="off" method="post" ACTION="grv_matriculas.php">

    <fieldset>

            <script language='JavaScript'>

                function only_number(){

                    if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)

                    event.returnValue=false;

                }
                function valida_cpf(){
                    // Verifica o CPF
                    if ( valida_cpf( 'cpf' ) 
                        <hr> CPF OK </hr>

                    event.returnValue=false;

                }

            </script>

            <legend>Formulário</legend>
            <br><label>Nome do aluno:</label><br><input class=longo type="text" name="aluno" required placeholder="Nome completo.">

            <br><label>CPF do aluno:</label><br><input class=curto type="number" name="cpf" onchange='valida_cpf()' required placeholder="Informe o cpf.">

            <br><label>Nome do responsavel:</label><br><input class=longo type="text" name="responsavel" required placeholder="Informe nome completo responsavel">

            <br><label>Endereço:</label><br>
               <input class=longo type="text" name="endereco" required placeholder="Informe endereço completo do responsavel.">

            <br><label>Telefone Celular:</label><br>
               <input class=curto type="number" name="fone" required placeholder="Informe o número.">

            <br><label>Endereço Eletronico:</label><br>
                <input class=longo type="text" name="mail" required placeholder="Informe e-mail do responsavel.">

            <br><label>Turma Pretendida:</label><br>

                <div>
                   <input type="radio" name="pretendido" value="bercario1" required checked>Berçario 1</input> 
                   <input type="radio" name="pretendido" value="bercario2" >Berçario 2</input>
                   <input type="radio" name="pretendido" value="maternal1">Maternal 1</input> 
                   <input type="radio" name="pretendido" value="maternal2">Maternal 2</input> 
                </div>

            <label>Escola:</label><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="escola" value="bemmequer" required checked>Bem me Quer</input>
            <div>                       

        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Enviar"> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

grv_matriculas.php

```
query($sql); 
$row = $resulta->fetch_assoc(); 
if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) { 
    $sql1 = "UPDATE lista SET aluno = '$aluno', responsavel = '$responsavel', endereco = '$endereco', fone = '$fone', mail = '$mail', pretendido = '$pretendido', escola = '$escola', dia_visita = '$dia_visita', hora_visita = '$hora_visita' WHERE cpf = '$cpf'": 
} else { 
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO lista(aluno, cpf, responsavel, endereco, fone, mail, 
pretendido, escola, ip, dia_visita, hora_visita) VALUES ('$aluno', '$cpf', 
'$responsavel', '$endereco', '$fone', '$mail', '$pretendido', '$escola', '$ip', 
'$dia_visita', '$hora_visita')"); 
} 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); 
echo $resultado; 
echo "alert('Gravado com Sucesso!);location.href='coloqueoarquivo.php';"; ?>
```

código para salvar

```
<?php
   include_once("conexao.php"); 

     $aluno=$_POST['aluno'];
     $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
     $responsavel=$_POST['responsavel'];
     $endereco=$_POST['endereco'];
     $fone=$_POST['fone'];
     $mail=$_POST['mail'];
     $pretendido=$_POST['pretendido'];
     $escola=$_POST['escola'];
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $dia_visita = date("d-m-y");
     $hora_visita = date("H:i:s");
     $oficial=$_POST['oficial'];

     $sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO lista(aluno, cpf, responsavel, endereco, fone, mail, pretendido, escola, ip, dia_visita, hora_visita, oficial)VALUES('$aluno', '$cpf', '$responsavel', '$endereco', '$fone', '$mail', '$pretendido', '$escola', '$ip, '$dia_visita', '$hora_visita', '$oficial')");

        echo  "<script>alert('Gravado com Sucesso!);</script>";
        header("Location: /Central_de_Matriculas/Best")

?>
```

Dentro do include de conexão ta definido como $conn. O que está errado?

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: falta uma aspas no $ip

Comment: namoral, estude um pouco PHP pois, seu código é mal identado, você fecha a tag input coisa que nunca vi, dá espaços extensos, e também definiu script language='JavaScript', na verdade é <script type="text/javascript"> será melhor para você senão sempre irá depender de alguém consertar seus códigos

Comment: Olá Victor, como eu disse sou novo por aqui, e também na area, porém o que não aprendo nas faculdades hoje em dia, tenho que buscar fora, muito obrigado pela ajuda, sabe onde mais posso encontrar material para estudo?

Comment: @Stormwind eu copiei este código da própria resposta dele e mandei ele remover a resposta, então editei adicionando os dados na resposta, e o arquivo grv_matricula, se reparar ele se baseou na minha resposta porém, editou e fez alterações desnecessárias

Comment: @CarlitoVeeckPautz verifique meu código e faça o que indiquei, cole ele no seu arquivo de inserção do banco de dados, e repare que você tem alguns posts que não estão recebendo nada através do formulário, isto pode estar lhe impedido

Comment: @Victor quando for assim, comente no campo de justificativa de edição, não tem como a gente descobrir isso na hora de analisar. Eu já estava revertendo sua edição.

Comment: desculpe nunca tinha pego um caso deste, de a pessoa colocar a resposta no lugar da pergunta entende. mas obrigado @Articuno numa próxima irei colocar

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando uma aspas simples "'" após a variável **$ip**, segue corrigido:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO lista(
                aluno, 
                cpf, 
                responsavel, 
                endereco, 
                fone, 
                mail, 
                pretendido, 
                escola, 
                ip, 
                dia_visita, 
                hora_visita, 
                oficial)
    VALUES(
      '$aluno', 
      '$cpf', 
      '$responsavel', 
      '$endereco', 
      '$fone', 
      '$mail', 
      '$pretendido', 
      '$escola', 
      '$ip', 
      '$dia_visita', 
      '$hora_visita', 
      '$oficial')";

$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Repare que na sua váriável `$ip` está faltando uma aspas simples `'`, e eu faria o seu código para que a medida que alguém preenchesse o formulário e os dados fossem "novos" ele faria `INSERT` caso contrário reconheceria pelo cpf e faria apenas `UPDATE` e depois redirecionaria para o seu arquivo desejado. Segue o código

```
<?php
   include_once("conexao.php"); 

     $aluno = $_POST['aluno'];
     $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
     $responsavel = $_POST['responsavel'];
     $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
     $fone = $_POST['fone'];
     $mail = $_POST['mail'];
     $pretendido = $_POST['pretendido'];
     $escola = $_POST['escola'];
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $dia_visita = date("d-m-y");
     $hora_visita = date("H:i:s");
     $oficial = $_POST['oficial'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lista"; 
        $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

            if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {
                 $sql1 = "UPDATE lista SET aluno = '$aluno', responsavel = '$responsavel', endereco = '$endereco', fone = '$fone', mail = '$mail', 
                pretendido = '$pretendido', escola = '$escola', dia_visita = '$dia_visita', hora_visita = '$hora_visita', oficial = '$oficial'  WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";
            } else {
                $sql1 = "INSERT INTO lista(aluno, cpf, responsavel, endereco, fone, mail, pretendido, escola, ip, dia_visita, hora_visita, oficial)
                VALUES
                ('$aluno', '$cpf', '$responsavel', '$endereco', '$fone', '$mail', '$pretendido', '$escola', '$ip', '$dia_visita', '$hora_visita', '$oficial')");
            }

            $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
            echo $sql1;


        echo  "<script>alert('Gravado com Sucesso!);location.href='coloqueoarquivo.php';</script>"; 

?>
```

Comment: Então, eu criei um código aqui e você deve copiar e colar ele para dar certo no seu arquivo criado para salvar as informações, afinal você editou o código que coloquei e no fim da linha do update repare na sua pergunta, tem ':' invés de um ';' coisa que fará  nunca dar certo mesmo seu código. E outra coisa se a tente que no seu html você não tem as variáveis $ip, $dia_visita, $hora_visita e $oficial